# Oracle 11g to 19c - Upgrade Error

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, upgrade, oracle-19c

We upgraded our test database from 11gR2 to 19c (19.12) (OS OL 7.9).
After the upgrade, all the components in the dba_registry seem to be in the UPGRADED state, not VALID. At the same time, we encountered about 20000 invalid objects after upgrade (none of the SYS or SYSTEM objects are invalid). When we run UTLRP, we get ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel and ORA-03114 errors. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Are you sure it's possible to skip from 11 to 19?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille of course. We upgraded 5 times from 11gR2 to 19c.

Comment: OK, in that case there must be something specific to this one.  You should be able to find an internal server error at the time of the ORA-03113.  Check the server logs for an ORA-600.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I checked. There are no invalid objects in SYS or SYSTEM. Upgrade completed successfully. But when I select dba_registry, all of the components are UPGRADED. I'm looking for why they are not in VALID state and why 20k invalid objects. I tried 10-15 different Oracle Support documents on the subject, but none of them worked. Now if there is someone who has just experienced this, I need that.

Comment: So, you have an ORA-03113 client side  but no internal error in the alert log?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I spooled this command: select 'alter '||object_type||' '||owner||'.'||object_name||' compile;' from dba_objects where status='INVALID'; and tried to compile manually. Now, there are 7k invalid objects. But I don't understand what is the main problem. When I check, there are no internal errors.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I solved the problem. I ran again and again the spooled command. After all, the utlrp worked and all of the components seem valid.

Comment: Stubbornness characterises a good ITer.

Comment: did you randamonly checked what was the error while making valid to an object?